# Rails ActiveRecord returns different results than the database

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql

I'm struggling to understand why the psql cli returns different results than my models. When I run the app, the logs show

```
  Ingredient Load (0.4ms)  SELECT "ingredients".* FROM "ingredients"
```

which returns no results. I confirmed this using [byebug](https://github.com/deivid-rodriguez/byebug) -- there is no query, find, all or otherwise, that returns results; instead I get an empty relation:

```
(byebug) Ingredient.all
  Ingredient Load (1.3ms)  SELECT  "ingredients".* FROM "ingredients" LIMIT $1  [["LIMIT", 11]]
#<ActiveRecord::Relation []>
```

. When I run `psql`, however, and run the same query, I get results:

```
 id |    name     | description |         created_at         |         updated_at         | deleted_at | short | color
----+-------------+-------------+----------------------------+----------------------------+------------+-------+--------
  1 | Thoughts    |             | 2016-04-26 17:38:47.813025 | 2017-08-30 17:32:47.374194 |            |       | 6C39FF
  2 | Calm        |             | 2016-04-26 17:41:35.926608 | 2017-08-30 17:33:05.416529 |            |       | 00B0EC
...snip...
(8 rows)
```

I checked the connection in database.yml, and I've made a few changes:

```
development:
  <<: *default
  database: life_development
  username: postgres
  password: postgres
  host: localhost
  port: 5432
```

But the database is owned by the same user

```
doug=# \l
                                 List of databases
       Name       |  Owner   | Encoding | Collate |  Ctype  |   Access privileges
------------------+----------+----------+---------+---------+-----------------------
 life             | postgres | UTF8     | C.UTF-8 | C.UTF-8 |
 life_development | postgres | UTF8     | C.UTF-8 | C.UTF-8 |
 life_test        | postgres | UTF8     | C.UTF-8 | C.UTF-8 |
 postgres         | postgres | UTF8     | C.UTF-8 | C.UTF-8 |
...snip...
(8 rows)
```

I'm running "rails", "~> 5.1.4" and "pg", "~> 1.2.3" with Postgres 11.11 on Ruby 2.7.2.
Any help would be well appreciated.

Comment: What does `ActiveRecord::Base.connection.current_database` returns?

Comment: What does `User.connection_config` return?

Comment: @muistooshort I do not -- that's stray formatting from my question.  

@SebastianPalma It returns the correct database:
```
(byebug) ActiveRecord::Base.connection.current_database
"life_development"
```  

@muistooshort `sudo -u postgres psql`    

@spickermann 
```
(byebug) User.connection_config
{:adapter=>"postgresql", :encoding=>"unicode", :pool=>5, :database=>"life_development", :username=>"postgres", :password=>"postgres", :host=>"localhost", :port=>5432}
```  

edit: formatting

Comment: I find the data in the database as expected (as shown above -- thoughts, calm etc.)

Comment: I also tried setting `self.table_name` to see if that helped, but it did not.

Comment: Using raw sql also doesn't produce any results:

`def self.raw_sql_all
    sql = "Select * from ingredients"
    ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute(sql)
  end`

Which yields

`(byebug) Ingredient.raw_sql_all
   (0.9ms)  Select * from ingredients
#<PG::Result:0x00007ffff10c7e40 status=PGRES_TUPLES_OK ntuples=0 nfields=8 cmd_tuples=0>`